# Javascript/Typescript: should decorator return a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, decorator

I am learning about decorators in Typescript which are used in Angular 2+. I understood that decorators are simply functions.

I found that sometimes decorators have to return a function and sometimes the logic is executed inside the decorator function without anything to return.

Consider the class decorator

```
@course
class Person {

    constructor() {
        console.log("Test")
    }
}
```

decorator course is defined as below. its defining some property of the Person.prototype. It returns nothing.

```
function course(target) {
    Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, 'course', {value: () => "Angular 2"})
}
```

Whereas:

```
@course{
    course:"Sample_decorator"
}
class Person {

    constructor() {
        console.log("Test")
    }
}
```

decorator course is defined as below. It returns a function.

```
function course(config) {
        return function (target) {
            Object.defineProperty(
                    target.prototype,
                    'course',
                    {value: () => config.course,
                    writable: true,
                    enumerable: true,
                    configurable: true
                } // 2
            )
        }
}
```

I am not able to undestand how the return function is automatically invoked. Because it involves two invocations.

If i invoke the above function manually:

say

```
test = {
    course:"Sample_decorator_testing"
}
```

First the decorator function is invoked:

```
var decor = course(test)
```

which return a function which has to be again invoked to run the defineproperty. So

```
decor(Person)
```

then only

```
sample = new Person
sample.course() \\ outputs "Sample_decorator_testing"
```

So how come its automatically invoking the return function.

Comment: Decorators have become popular thanks to their use in Angular 2+. In Angular, decorators are available thanks to TypeScript, but in JavaScript they are currently a stage 2 proposal, meaning they should be part of a future update to the language. https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-decorators-what-they-are/

Comment: Typescript ones which are used in Angular 4

Answer (score 1):

According to the [spec proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/) you can have two types of decorators:

- member decorator function

> A member decorator function is a function which takes a member
>   descriptor and which returns a member descriptor

- class decorator function

> A class decorator function is a function which takes a constructor,
>   heritage (parent class), and an array of MemberDescriptors that
>   represent the instance and static members of the class.

You can also have several chained decorators. If that's the case the value returned by a decorator becomes the input of the next decorator.

So, the decorator function is supposed to be used like this:

```
class Person {
  @deprecate
  facepalm() {}
```

What's interesting is that the `@` should be followed by **expression** that should **evaluate** into `decorator` function. It means that you can use a function after the `@` symbol that will return a decorator function:

```
class Person {

  @deprecate('We stopped facepalming')
  facepalmHard() {}
```

In that case the decorator will be implemented like this:

```
function deprecate(descriptor) {
   return deprecateDecoratorFunction(class, descriptorName, descriptor) {
```

According to the proposal the following syntax is correct:

```
@decoratorFunction                       // IdentifierReference
@customObject.decoratorFunction          // IdentifierReference . IdentifierName
@decoratorFunction(...)                  // IdentifierReference Arguments
@customObject.decoratorFunction(...)     // IdentifierReference . IdentifierName Arguments
```

Also read:

- [Implementing custom component decorator in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular-4d037d5a3f0d)